Excel VBA returned error said "This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing"
This is the code generated by Copilot. At first it worked perfectly fine but then it has an error "This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing" on the line pic.paste where I 4 stars **** it.
Sub CopyRangesToOutlook()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim wsDaily As Worksheet
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pic As Object
    Dim rngArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Set worksheets
    Set wsDaily = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily E-Mail (1)")
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input MTM (AFS)")
    
    ' Create Outlook application and mail item
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Array of ranges to copy as pictures
    rngArray = Array("I226:L3292", "I337:N4423", "Q3:S2214")
    
    ' Loop through ranges and copy as pictures
    For i = LBound(rngArray) To UBound(rngArray)
        Set rng = wsDaily.Range(rngArray(i))
        rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
        Set pic = OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection
        pic.Paste****
        pic.TypeParagraph
    Next i
    
    ' Copy ranges U102:U217 and Y102:Y112 as normal text
    Set rng = wsDaily.Range("U102:U217")
    rng.Copy
    OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
    OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
    
    Set rng = wsDaily.Range("Y102:Y112")
    rng.Copy
    OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
    OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
    
    ' Copy last row - 2 from Input MTM (AFS) sheet
    lastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = wsInput.Range("L" & lastRow - 2 & ":Q" & lastRow - 2)
    rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    Set pic = OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection
    pic.Paste
    pic.TypeParagraph
    
    ' Set email properties
    With OutlookMail
        .Subject = "Daily Report"
        .To = "recipient@example.com"
        .BodyFormat = 2 ' HTML format
        .Display ' or use .Send to send the email directly
    End With
    
    ' Clean up
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub

I don't think my file is locked for editing at all since I can edit every thing in my workbook and I've already tried every method that listed in google already and it didn't help.

The error "This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing" often arises due to issues with the interaction between Excel and Outlook.
